# Populate object key without using mongoose/mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose

I have this Mongoose Object:

```
recipe = {
     "ingredients": [
        {
          "_id": "5fc8b729c47c6f38b472078a",
          "ingredient": {
            "unit": "ml",
            "name": "olive oil",
            "createdAt": "2020-10-09T10:53:35.567Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-12-03T09:25:43.282Z",
            "unitConversion": [
              {
                "_id": "5fc0a688c1799719d03aea3f",
                "value": 20,
                "convertedValue": 1,
                "unitMeasure": {
                  "name": "spoon",
                  "createdAt": "2020-11-19T07:31:11.353Z",
                  "updatedAt": "2020-11-19T07:31:11.353Z",
                  "id": "5fb61f3f0a62dc27fc052271"
                }
              }
            ],
            "id": "5f80412f583af20c8c0aeea1"
          },
          "quantity": 2,
          "unitConv": "5fc0a688c1799719d03aea3f"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do, populate the unitConv with the object from unitConversion array that has a matching id.

Here is my code:

```
const newRecipe = recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
        let unit
        if (ingredient.unitConv && ingredient.unitConv !== null) {
          unit = ingredient.ingredient.unitConversion.reduce((unit) => {
            if (unit.id === ingredient.unitConv) {
              return unit
            }
          })
          ingredient.unitConv = unit
        }
        return ingredient
      })
```

It works. `ingredient.unitConv` gets populated with the object with the matching id from the unitConversion array, but is not an object. It's being added as a string.
This is how ingredient.unitConv is being populated:

```
"unitConv": "{\n  _id: 5fc0a688c1799719d03aea3f,\n  value: 20,\n  convertedValue: 1,\n  unitMeasure: {\n    _id: 5fb61f3f0a62dc27fc052271,\n    name: 'spoon',\n    createdAt: 2020-11-19T07:31:11.353Z,\n    updatedAt: 2020-11-19T07:31:11.353Z,\n  }\n}"
```

I tried using JSON.parse() on it, but it won't work, I will get several errors of SyntaxError type (Unexpected token in JSON at position...). I tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('the object')), but this won't populate at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your environment it is probably a string, but when passing the code here, it remains as an object. Try to check the data type like this:

```js
recipe = {
  ingredients: [
    {
      _id: '5fc8b729c47c6f38b472078a',
      ingredient: {
        unit: 'ml',
        name: 'olive oil',
        createdAt: '2020-10-09T10:53:35.567Z',
        updatedAt: '2020-12-03T09:25:43.282Z',
        unitConversion: [
          {
            _id: '5fc0a688c1799719d03aea3f',
            value: 20,
            convertedValue: 1,
            unitMeasure: {
              name: 'spoon',
              createdAt: '2020-11-19T07:31:11.353Z',
              updatedAt: '2020-11-19T07:31:11.353Z',
              id: '5fb61f3f0a62dc27fc052271',
            },
          },
        ],
        id: '5f80412f583af20c8c0aeea1',
      },
      quantity: 2,
      unitConv: '5fc0a688c1799719d03aea3f',
    },
  ],
};

const newRecipe = recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
  let unit;
  if (ingredient.unitConv && ingredient.unitConv !== null) {
    unit = ingredient.ingredient.unitConversion.reduce((unit) => {
      if (unit.id === ingredient.unitConv) {
        return unit;
      }
    });
    ingredient.unitConv = unit;
  }
  return ingredient;
});
console.log(`unitConv is an ${typeof newRecipe[0].unitConv}`);
```

Comment: the typeof newRecipe[0].unitConv it's string.

Comment: In my mongoose model, I have it declared as a string (unitConv: String). Might this be the problem, for not being passed as an object, but a string?

Comment: you should declare it as object like this example:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to user **filter** function  instead of **reduce** function in your code. In this case you will get a array of objects. Also please check the type of *unitConv* in your schema.